# Postgres view returning phantom data from view to Access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

From Access, selecting against a table works while a view does not.

Postgres, v9.4
New version of MS-Access 365, v2303
Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode, v13.02 9/22/2021
Parameters: PORT=5432;A1=7.4-1;B0=255;B1=8190;B6=0;C2=dd_;

Selecting against the Deposit table in Postgres returns the correct data and the correct number of rows. 5 records, all different, as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM "Deposits"
WHERE "Deposit_Slip_Number"='2305-6';
```

Selecting against a view in Postgres returns the correct data and the correct number of rows. 15 records, all different, as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM "vw_rptDeposits_OnBankStatement"
WHERE "Deposit_Slip_Number"='2305-6';
```

Selecting against the Deposit table in Access returns the correct data and the correct number of rows. 5 records all different, as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM Deposits
WHERE Deposit_Slip_Number='2305-6';
```

Selecting against the view in Access returns **incorrect** data but the correct number of rows. 15 records **all the same** as the first record, NOT as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_rptDeposits_OnBankStatement
WHERE Deposit_Slip_Number='2305-6';
```

I've rebooted my machine, restarted the postgres service.
The driver hasn't changed in about a year.
If I point Access at a different server, same results, table works, view does not.
The only thing that has changed is that I'm working on the view, but that shouldn't affect how it transfers data. And the other database has the original view.
The views and tables are just pass-thru tables, linked to Postgres, no dependency on anything local to Access.
These are DNS-less tables linked through code.
All other views look correct.

Comment: I would remove the linked view, link it again, make sure you specify the PK when doing so. If you have edited the view on the server, this can be necessary.

Comment: If that doesn't help you may want to turn on ODBC tracing: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189062/trace-odbc-commands-what-is-the-registry-path-for-tracesqlmode-and-where-is-sql

Comment: The primary key was Deposit_Slip_Number which is probably not the best choice. I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: Creating a unique ID to use as the PK did the trick. Could you add something like that as an answer?

Comment: To narrow down the problem, set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` on the PostgreSQL server so that all SQL statements get logged. Then see what is really executed. Then you know if it is a database problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking ODBC Views in Access, you need to specify a unique PK for them to work correctly.

The usual problem if no PK is given is that the linked view is read-only.

But if you specify a non-unique column as PK, all sorts of problems can occur.

For linked ODBC tables, the PK is identified automatically (at least for MSSQL).

Comment: This did the trick. The column I was using was not unique. I had to add a new column with an autogenerated unique id and use that as the key. Views in Postgres can't have PK, or it would have flagged to problem. Since I was adding the key on the Access side, it didn't know any better.